# C++ Overloading of operator '<' is not being used every time

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, overloading

I have a person object with attributes such as name, surname, etc...I also have 3-4 classes which inherit from the person class.

I have another class which will print all the different types of person in ascending order. So, I have overloaded the operator '<' and I know it works as I have used it elsewhere. But for some reason, it is not being used in this specific method which is in a different class.

this is my overloading method found in the person class.

```
    bool person::operator< ( const person &p2 ) const
    {    
        if ( surname() < p2.surname() )
           return true;
        else 
        //There are many other conditions which return true or false depending on the attributes.
    }
```

This is the method found in another class (a subclass) which should use the overloaded operator but does not seem to make use of it.

```
 vector<person *> contacts::sorted_contacts() const{

    vector<person *> v_contact;

    auto comparison = [] ( person *a, person *b ){  return a < b ;  };  

    //Some code here which fills in the vector

    sort(begin(v_contact), end(v_contact), comparison);
}
```

The sort here does not work. Because, when I use copy/paste the implementation of the overloading and put it here, the vector is sorted correctly. Because I want to re-use code, I'm trying to figure out why the operator `<` is not being used here.

Comment: Pointers already have an `operator<`. It's impossible to provide your own.

Comment: Your overloaded `<` won't work for container elements as pointers

Comment: @chris: Unless, like here, you provide a comparator argument to `sort`. But that should compare the objects, rather than the pointers.

Comment: write *a < *b instead.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, Yeah, I'm not honestly completely sure what I was going for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here

```
auto comparison = [] ( person *a, person *b ){  return a < b ;  }
```

you are comparing pointers instead of comparing the objects themselves.

In order to compare the actual objects (which apparently was your intent) you have to dereference the pointers. It also makes sense to const-qualify your pointers properly

```
auto comparison = [] ( const person *a, const person *b ){  return *a < *b ;  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I cannot believe that I did not see that:'(

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
auto comparison = [] ( person *a, person *b ){  return a < b ;  }
```

compares the pointers, not the persons.

```
auto comparison = [] ( person *a, person *b ){  return *a < *b ;  }
```

will compare the persons.